How can we change the envoyproxy timeout of 15 seconds
I have an application deployed on K8s and I'm using envoyproxy as a sidecar. The image of the envoy that I'm using is "docker.io/envoyproxy/envoy:v1.16.0". Currently, the issue that I'm facing is that the envoy proxy times out in 15 seconds. For some APIs, it is taking more than 15 seconds to get the response, and in that case, the envoy proxy timeout is breaking the connection.
I'm using a helm based deployment and using the below code to configure the envoy:
ContainerPort:
  - envoyPort: 8799
    idleTimeout: 1800s
    name: app
    port: 5000
    servicePort: 80
    supportStreaming: false
    useHTTP2: false

What is the parameter that I can use to increase the timeout or where can I find more details on this? I've tried with "envoyTimeout", "timeout", etc and nothing worked.
Please point me at the right direction. Thanks in advance.

do you want to configure idle timeout?
